# How to concat arrays immutable way JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I wonder how to contact array that is immutable. Lets imagine I start with array `list = [4,1]`, and then I receive array from action response like so `items = [5,2,6]`. How do I concant arrays that the result is `[4,1,5,2,6]` and that operation is not mutable.

**Bonus**: How do I overwrite items with same id (immutable way)? Lets imagine this our array in store `books=[{'id':1, 'title': 'Cool story'}, {'id':2, 'title': 'Bad story'}]`. Other array that needs to overwrite books (last sync from API) `otherArray = [{'id':3, 'title': 'Super story'}, {'id':1, 'title': 'Very cool story'}]`. So result should be `[{'id':2, 'title': 'Bad story'}], {'id':3, 'title': 'Super story'}, {'id':1, 'title': 'Very cool story'}]`

Comment: *"Bonus"* No. Ask **one** question per question, not two. If you have a second question, ask it separately (after having done thorough research, of course).

Comment: *"How do I overwrite items with same id (immutable way)?"* You don't. You create a *new* array with a different value in one of the slots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript does not have immutable types.

It sounds like you're actually asking to concatenate arrays without *mutating* the existing instances.

As stated clearly in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), the `concat()` method does that.

Comment: Number and String are immutables in Javascript.   

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Mutable

Answer (score 15):

With **ES6** you can use destructuring:

```
const array1 = ["Banana","Apple"];
const array2 = ["Pineapple", "Peach"];
const array3 = [...array1, ...array2];
```

Comment: this is better than the accepted answer for most modern use cases

Answer (score 1):

Although as mentioned, the built-in method `.concat()` will solve your problem, you might wish to look into the [Lodash library](https://lodash.com).  In particular, the bonus question could be solved with `_.unionBy(otherArray, books, "id")`.